# Python parentheses and returning only certain part of regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings that I'm looping through. I have the following regular expression (item is the string I'm looping through at any given moment):

```
regularexpression = re.compile(r'set(\d+)e', re.IGNORECASE)
number = re.search(regularexpression,item).group(1)
```

What I want it to do is return numbers that have the word set before them and the letter e after them.

However, I also want it to return numbers that have set before them and x after them. If I use the following code:

```
regularexpression = re.compile(r'set(\d+)(e|x)', re.IGNORECASE)
number = re.search(regularexpression,item).group(1)
```

Instead of returning just the number, it also returns e or x. Is there a way to use parentheses to group my regular expression into bits without it returning everything in the parentheses?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: As an aside, after compiling the regular expression you can use it directly: `regularexpression.search(item).group(1)`.

Comment: Could you provide some sample strings that are used as `item`?

Answer (score 3):

Your example code seems fine already, but to answer your question, you can make a *non-capturing group* using the `(?:)` syntax, e.g.:

```
set(\d+)(?:e|x)
```

Additionally, in this specific example you can just use a character class:

```
set(\d+)[ex]
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are looking at more than just `.group(1)`; you have two capturing groups defined in your regular expression.

You can make the second group non-capturing by using `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`:

```
regularexpression = re.compile(r'set(\d+)(?:e|x)', re.IGNORECASE)
```